# Laravel Email Templates on Production Server

Tags: laravel

On my local development server I have changed the default email templates, however, once I have pushed to the production server I notice that those changes don't push because the vendor folder is included in the gitignore file.

What is the best way to get my local changes moved to the production server? I have already published the files on the production server, but how would I access those files to make the changes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely commit contents of the `vendor` directory inside `resources/views`. If no `.gitignore` is present in the `resources/views` directory, add one with the content `!/vendor`. This will unignore the `vendor` directory within this path.

---

**Side note:**
I guess you have `vendor/` written in the `.gitignore` of your projects root directory. This is a special syntax that will use inheritance across your project, meaning the `vendor` directory is not only ignored in the root directory, but also all sub directories. In theory, if you change the entry to `/vendor`, the other `vendor` directory within `resources/views` should be unignored automatically without an extra .gitignore. But be careful to not unignore other unwanted `vendor` directories...

Comment: The default "vendor/" is in the .gitignore file as you note. When I add "!/vendor" to the .gitignore file, in my Github GUI I see it wanting to commit 7,000+ files.

Comment: Did you add the line in `<project-directory>/.gitignore` or `<project-directory>/resources/views/.gitignore`? The latter is what you want.

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Adding "!resources/views/vendor" adds just 29 files. Problem solved. Thank you. I'll mark your answer.